# Kotlin: Why isn't there a loop Expression?

Tags: kotlin

This would seem so simple:

```
val uuids = repeat(5) { UUID.randomUUID() }  // doesn't work as desired
```

but instead I need to use a mutableList and use one of the various loops that return Unit.   Or this:

```
val uuids = (1..5).map { UUID.randomUUID() }
```

It just seems odd that Kotlin left out a construct for looping expressions.  Did I miss something?  If not, any ideas why as I don't consider Kotlin a functional language without them?  Is this a future item?

Comment: val uuids = List(5) { UUID.randomUUID() }

Comment: ["Why" something is not in the language is not a good question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293819/5133585) Yous should be *very* clear about the kind of answers you are looking for.

Comment: Kotlin is an imperative language with some functional programming features.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "loop expression"? In functional languages, loops are usually implemented using recursion. Kotlin also support recursion, and even does tail recursion optimization if you use the `tailrec` keyword. Can you show an example of what you consider a "loop expression" in some other language, so we can tell you what the Kotlin equivalent is?

Answer (score 7):

You've missed something: `List(5) { UUID.randomUUID() }`.

Comment: The example was contrived, but thank you.